# How to delete a locally installed version of pgf?

Tags: installing, tikz-pgf, texmf

I have a locally installed `pgf` in my local texmf tree.  Now my tex distribution finally caught up and the version of pfg in the package manager is newer than my locally installed version.  How can I delete the local version?

Comment: The reason I am asking is that there are number of answers on this site recommending people to install a local copy of pgf in order to get the newest and greatest features.  But we never seem to tell anybody that when they do that, they are actually taking over their package managers handling of pgf, and are now responsible for updating pgf themselves. I thought that in addition of having a guide for installing a local copy of pgf, we should also have one on removing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete all associated files manually and then refresh the filename database (FNDB). The details of this process depend on your OS.

Comment: But how do I know what all the associated files are?

Comment: See Andrew's answer below.

Comment: Now I see why I try to avoid using `above` and `below` ...

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but it might be that we have some serious misunderstanding here. My above comment was meant on the funny side (forgot to put some `:-)`). It was not meant as a critique to you answer, nor did I downvote the answer. If you have no idea why I put this new comment here, then maybe my wild guess was incorrect. If you have an idea, then I would be very grateful for a confirmation that my guess was correct. @Anybody else who has no idea what this is about: Sorry; I hope that I'm not abusing the comment function too heavily here.

Comment: I still have the feeling that I offended you somehow. I'd really like to know, is there anything I can clarify? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To find out what files, you can get hold of the original archive that you got `pgf` from and list the files, then you can use that list to delete the right files.

I'm using `zsh` on a Linux machine, and I downloaded the `pgf` tree into my `Desktop` folder, so in my `texmf` directory, I could do:

```
for f in $(unzip -ql ~/Desktop/pgf_2.10.tds.zip); do
[[ -e $f && -f $f ]] && rm $f
done
```

To remove any empty directories, you could then do

```
for f in $(unzip -ql ~/Desktop/pgf_2.10.tds.zip); do
[[ -e $f && -d $f ]] && rmdir -p $f
done
```

Note that `rmdir` only deletes empty directories so it's safe.  You have to do this afterwards, and you have to specify the `-p` (remove parents) because directories tend to be listed *first* in the archive, so in the archive you might have:

```
a
a/b
a/b/c.txt
```

but when deleting them, you need to delete them in reverse order.

(I suppose you could modify the original script to reverse the order:

```
for f in $(unzip -ql ~/Desktop/pgf_2.10.tds.zip | tac); do
[[ -e $f && -f $f ]] && rm $f
[[ -e $f && -d $f ]] && rmdir $f
done
```

if you really wanted to)

You could also just move them out of the way, rather than deleting them.  And I'd recommend making a backup of your `texmf` tree **before** doing this in case you accidentally delete a file that you shouldn't have done.

Comment: On my system, `unzip -ql` returns some other info for each file, each line looks like `     7507  2010-10-25 17:00   tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-plain.def`. That can be easily fixed by filtering the output through `cut`.

Comment: @Jan: I don't know why, but I couldn't get `cut` to cut anything!  That's why I put the `-e $f` bit in: it tests to see if `$f` corresponds to something on the filesystem (I guess there's a danger that you have a file called `7507`, of course).  If you (or anyone else) can figure out the appropriate `cut` syntax, I'll happily add it in.

Comment: This works for me: `unzip -ql pgf_2.10.tds.zip | cut -b 31-`.  I don't know if the 31 is the same on all systems and all versions of unzip, though.

Answer (score 4):

Thorsten's and Andrew's answers are excellent, and will pertain to any package that you have installed locally which now needs to be removed.  However, there may be an easier way.  It seems that all files that the pgf package contains, at least in version 2.10, is contained in one of the following directories:

```
doc/generic/pgf/
scripts/pgf/
source/latex/pgf/
tex/context/third/pgf/
tex/latex/pgf/
tex/plain/pgf/
tex/generic/pgf/
```

except the `README` file that is in the root of the archive.  As far as I can tell, no other package should put anything in those directories, so removing these 7 directories with their contents and refreshing the filename database should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

This looks for all the subdirectories named `pgf` in the user's texmf directory, then deletes them.

```
find ${TEXMFHOME} -type d -name pgf | xargs rm -rf
```

Use `rm -rf` with caution, of course!

Comment: Nice.  I would suggest to first try a dry run: `find <user's texmf directory> -type d -name pgf | xargs echo`, to see what is going to get removed.

Answer (score 2):

In miktex I don't install a local pgf in "the" local texmf tree. I put all the pgf-files in a new texmf tree only for pgf (called eg. testpgf) and then "mount" this tree as a new local texmf tree in miktex settings. When I no longer need this pgf, I "unmount" and then delete the complete tree.

Comment: That's a great way to keep things organised!